# javafx background image position outside of hbox

Tags: java, javafx, background-position, hbox

The problem occurs when `-fx_background-position:0 -40` is set either by a loaded *style.css* or in code via an action handler. 
In my example the background image is set on an `hbox` width one cell. When adjusting position the background image, the image moves outside of the limits/borders of the `hbox`, up in this case, and covers an area over the position of the `hbox`. In my case it covers action buttons so they don't fire. 
How to not show the part of the background image that is outside of `hbox`?

Answer (score 0):

If your overlapping hbox should not react on MouseEvents at all, you can add `hbox.setMouseTransparent(true);`

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, thats ok, but in this case it will cover a range of 8 buttons som it difficult to hit the right one..., thanks for answering. 2 of the buttons moves the background image up an down.